# Execute SelectionChangedEvent from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, command, selectionchanged

```
public ICommand SelectionChanged
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(param => this.ExecuteSelectionChanged(param));
    }
}

private object ExecuteSelectionChanged(object param)
{
    var e = param as SelectionChangedEventArgs;
    var addedItem = e.AddedItems[0];
}
```

I want to do:

```
SelectionChanged.Execute(new SelectionChangedEventArgs( null,null, addedList));
```

But it is saying value cannot be null of event id. Any work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   SelectionChanged.Execute(new SelectionChangedEventArgs(ComboBox.SelectionChangedEvent, removeList,addList));
```

Comment: Please add some details to the code example to explain which parts of it solve the problem. Include links to relevant documentation/reading if possible.